# laravel controller form array value compere if same pass 1 not pass 0

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm new to laravel I was trying to get value IN controller form array value compere all "ANSWER" AND "OPTION" array value.

**EXAMPLE**

ANSWER AND OPTION if
ANSWER 0=>A EQUELS OPTION=>A  pass 1
ANSWER 0=>B EQUELS OPTION=>A  pass 0

THIS VALUE STORE IN ANSWER_STATUS COLUMANE

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public function Store_Answer(Request $request)
   {
     $count= $request->Question;
     if ($count) {
     for ($i=0; $i <count($request->Question); $i++) {
     $data = New OnlineExminAnswer();
     $data->ANSWER_STATUS= $request->ANSWER_STATUS; // HERE I WANT TO GET VALUE OF COMPARED 1 OR 0
     $data->question = $request->Question [$i];
     $data->answer = $request->OPTION[$i];
     $data->save();
  } 
     }
```

**my form array**

```
  "Question" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "YOUR NAME"
    1 => "water formula in science"
  ]
  "ANSWER" => array:2 [▼  //THIS ARRAY CONTAINING ALL RIGHT ANSWER
    0 => "A"
    1 => "h2O"
  ]
  "OPTION" => array:2 [▼  //THIS ARRAY STUDENTS ANSWER 
    0 => "A"
    1 => "CO2"
  ]
]
```

Comment: `$request->ANSWER[$i]` will give you correct answer if your indexes are same. `$request->ANSWER[$i] == $request->OPTION[$i]` will do the job according to info you posted.

Comment: @Insane Skull hello $request->ANSWER[$i] == $request->OPTION[$i] how i get 0 for not Mach 1 for value Mach i have to pass 0 or 1 in   ANSWER_STATUS columane

Comment: Yes you can compare like this, `$data->ANSWER_STATUS = $request->ANSWER[$i] == $request->OPTION[$i] ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @Insane Skull I'm new to laravel is there possible to add this in my controller for batter understand post your as answer it helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function Store_Answer(Request $request)
{
    $count = $request->Question;
    if ($count) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->Question); $i++) {
            if(isset($request->ANSWER[$i]) && isset($request->OPTION[$i])) {
                $data = new OnlineExminAnswer();
                $data->ANSWER_STATUS = $request->ANSWER[$i] == $request->OPTION[$i] ? 1 : 0;
                $data->question = $request->Question[$i];
                $data->answer = $request->OPTION[$i];
                $data->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing error Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: im facing error help me